# How to partition a table without time data?

Tags: postgresql, time-series-database, timescaledb

I am using [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) to store information about event ticket sales.

I have two tables: `event_sale` and `event_sale_seat`:

- `event_sale (id integer, created_at timestamp with time zone)`
- `event_sale_seat (id integer, event_sale_id integer REFERENCES event_sale(id), event_seat_id integer REFERENCES event_seat(id))`

The `event_sale` table is 200M records.
The `event_sale_seat` table is 1.5bn records.

Every time `event_sale` record is created, the corresponding `event_sale_seat` records are created as well, i.e. the latter table identifies which seats were sold.

The most common operation is getting all the `event_sale_seat` records for some `event_sale` criteria, e.g.

```
select
  es1.id event_sale_id,
  ess1.event_seat_id
from event_sale es1
inner join event_sale_seat ess1 on ess1.event_sale_id = es1.id
where es1.created_at BETWEEN now() - interval '1 month' and now();
```

As both tables are growing really large, I want to partition them, starting with `event_sale_seat` table.

I am considering of using https://www.timescale.com/.

My understanding that to partition a time-series database, I should have a column with a time value.

As I want to convert `event_sale_seat` to a [hypertable](https://docs.timescale.com/v1.1/using-timescaledb/hypertables) and this table does not have a column carrying a time value, my questions are:

- `event_sale_seat` does not have a column with meaningful time value. What column should be used for partitioning?
- suppose that I must/ should have a time column, would I just copy `event_sale.created_at` to `event_sale_seat`?
- how will the latter join example be performed when the table is partitioning by `created_at`?

Regarding the last question, would this be how the join is performed?

```
select
  es1.id event_sale_id,
  ess1.event_seat_id
from event_sale es1
inner join event_sale_seat ess1 on ess1.created_at = es1.created_at and ess1.event_sale_id = es1.id
where es1.created_at BETWEEN now() - interval '1 month' and now();
```

Comment: Someone with more reputation should create a timescale tag and add it to this question.

Comment: By now you can use [tag:time-series-database], I've added it to the question.

Comment: As there is not much information within the `event_sale` table, I would merge the two tables together creating a single de-normalized table that contains all the data. Then you would have a date within your `event_sale_seat` table.

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone Thats not the actual schema. Just the key components for the illustration purposes.

Comment: That's fair enough - but, is there anything stopping you from including the timestamp field in the `event_sale_seat` table?

Comment: There isn't – but what value should I use for it? (This question is posed in the original question.)